# Can a magical net be destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have been told by people that you can't destroy magic items.

A net gives you the option in its rules.

> Dealing 5 slashing damage to the net (AC 10) also frees the creature without
>   harming it, ending the effect and destroying the net.  (Basic Rules p. 47)

Can a *magic* net be destroyed?.

Comment: Oh apologizes i thought id just put both in one since they were such short questions and their are a few ways main one being Item Procurement from my faction choosing a net which is a martial ranged weapon

Comment: @True I've removed the extra question - it's already been asked and answered  [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86353/15469), anyway.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Yes, magic items can be destroyed.

The DMG has this to say about damaging magical items:

> Most magic items are objects of extraordinary craftsmanship. Thanks to a combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a nonmagical item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extraordinary measures to destroy.

So a magical net would generally have resistance to all damage, but would still come under the normal rules for nets, and could be destroyed by dealing 5 slashing damage (after its resistance was taken into account).

Note that these are just the baseline rules - all of this is up to your DM to determine, especially since a magical net is probably, although not necessarily, a homebrew item.