# How does damaging a Folding Boat work?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage

My players have acquired a Folding Boat in which they are about to go out on their first adventure on. Whilst I've been prepping the adventure I've started thinking around the magical properties of the boat that they will be travelling on.

Leaving aside the advantages and disadvantages of using a folding boat to travel the high seas, my question is specifically around what damage the boat does and does not take, specifically:

- Is there any RAW about whether this boat can be sunk, damaged by cannon fire etc
- If it is damaged, is that damage "persistent", i.e. does it stick with the boat when it is folded and unfolded

The DMG is very sparse in details about the Folding Boat, I think the majority of the details are captured on [Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Folding%20Boat#content). My main concern about damage is that this is obviously a magical item, and will therefore have magical properties.

Comment: There is no such thing as "general" or "untyped" damage in 5e afaik.

Comment: @Szega You are correct all damage has a type. Also, related: [Can a Magical Net be Destroyed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98753/can-a-magical-net-be-destroyed)

Comment: there is typeless damage, actually. If you check out the stirge's continuous damage after it attached to a target, you'll see there is no damage type specified. (MM p. 284)

Comment: Per the Stirge's description: "While attached, the stirge doesn't Attack. Instead, at the start of each of the stirge's turns, the target loses 5 (1d4 + 3) hit points due to blood loss."  Interesting. I don't know whether the HP decrease from blood loss is technically considered "damage"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Folding Boat](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemsAToZ.htm#foldingBoat) description says that it can unfold "*into a boat 10 feet long...*" or "*into a ship 24 feet long...*", so  we would normally treat it as such for most purposes (including the [Damaging Objects](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/objects.htm) rules, and the DMG p.119 Vehicle rules), except where noted otherwise (unlike [Instant Fortress](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemsAToZ.htm#instantFortress) or [Apparatus of the Crab](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemsAToZ.htm#apparatusOfTheCrab), which explicitly note how they can be damaged). One exception from DMG p.141 [states](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98753/can-a-magical-net-be-destroyed) that "*Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have [resistance](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/damageAndHealing.htm#damageResistanceAndVulnerability) to all damage*". This means that:

- The **Boat** would either be AC 11, 50 HP (DMG p.119 *rowboat*) or AC 15, 27 HP (large wooden [object](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/objects.htm)), and have [Resistance](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/damageAndHealing.htm#damageResistanceAndVulnerability) to all damage.
- The **Ship** would mostly ignore normal weapons ([since](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/objects.htm) "*Normal weapons are of little use against many Huge and Gargantuan objects*"), but versus siege weapons (DMG p.255) and such it would likely have AC 15, 300hp, 15 damage [threshold](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/objects.htm) (DMG p.119 *Sailing ship*), and have [Resistance](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/damageAndHealing.htm#damageResistanceAndVulnerability) to all damage.

Either should be repairable via the [Mending](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mending.htm) spell. However, there is no indication that the vehicle(s) self repair when folded up, so I wouldn't assume this.

Comment: Does the fact that it is a magic item not affect damage at all?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose See the related question I commented on the OP for rules on damaging magic items.

Comment: @DavidCoffron it's probably worth putting in your answer since OP specifically asked about it, but that's up to you.

Comment: @Rubicksmoose. Not my answer to add to.

Comment: Good input: I have added information on damage resistance.

Comment: @DavidCoffron sorry I was on mobile and didn't check. Just assumed you were OP.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a pretty solid roundup of all the different damage considerations