# Can a druid wildshaped into a giant spider use the Sharpshooter feat on its web attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, druid, wild-shape, ranged-attack

If a Moon Druid is wildshaped into a Giant Spider, which has a web attack (which is classified by the MM as a ranged weapon attack), can he then use the Sharpshooter feat to gain a +10 to damage since it's a ranged weapon attack anyway?

Answer (score 17):

### No, they can't use Sharpshooter on their web attack

Sharpshooter's third benefit requires you to use a ranged weapon, not to make a ranged weapon attack.

> Before you make an attack **with a ranged weapon** that you are proficient with, [...]

Although Web is classified as a ranged weapon attack, it is not a ranged weapon, so it is ineligible for the ability.

From Jeremy Crawford's [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/996549348140826624) (emphasis mine)

> I'll boil it down for you. When we wrote the "Player's Handbook," we meant the **weapons on the weapon table** when we wrote "weapon," unless we said otherwise. But you break nothing in the game if you let natural weapons go along for the ride.

and [another one](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/739201714243264512)

> Their attacks count as weapon attacks, but the system **doesn't consider their body parts weapons.**

Although he said you can let natural weapon be counted as weapon, remember that web doesn't deal any damage, so in line with "[net cannot benefit from extra damage, like Sneak Attack and Sharpshooter](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86353/can-other-damage-from-class-abilities-feats-be-added-to-net-attacks)", web also cannot benefit from extra damage too.

And another Crawford's [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/586414191495393282) regarding this

> The intent is that a net doesn't deal extra damage because it's not dealing damage in the first place.