# Does using the Lucky Feat to tranform disadvantage into super-advantage still work with a net?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68970/how-is-the-lucky-feat-affected-by-advantage-disadvantage), it can be seen that using a luck point when doing something at a disadvantage essentially transforms it into super-advantage.

Does this specific strategy still works when throwing a net (which, by default, are always at a disadvantage due to their 5ft short range) ?

Comment: Is there a reason you think an attack with a net is different from any other d20 roll? If not I would call this a duplicate of the question you linked

Comment: @Medix2 It’s because someone told me “nets are always at disadvantage, so it doesn’t work here”, and it made me go “huh?”.

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami **Related question**: [Are attacks with nets always made at disadvantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47754/are-attacks-with-nets-always-made-with-disadvantage)

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami Then I would suggest writing an answer that supports that :) In the meantime, comments are only for getting clarification or suggesting improvement to the question, so I'm going to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

### Nets do not have any special factor that removes this possibility.

The reason the Lucky feat works to replace disadvantage with "super-advantage" is because:

> You choose which of the d20s is used for the attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.

This means you are choosing between which of the three d20s (two from disadvantage and one from Lucky) *even though* usually you would take the lowest of the two from disadvantage. Giving you the ability to choose is what causes this to negate the disadvantage.

Nets are in an interesting state since they are [almost always at disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47754/41726) as you can either attack within 5 feet, or attack at long range. However, the Lucky feat still lets you choose which of the three d20s is used.