# Can you throw a net without disadvantage using the Crossbow Expert feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack

A net is a thrown weapon with a range of 5/15. This means that at 10 or 15 feet, you throw with disadvantage. However because of the *Ranged Attacks in Close Combat* rule you also throw at disadvantage at 5 feet (PHB, p. 195):

> ... When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who can see you and who isn't incapacitated.

Crossbow Expert (PHB, p.265):

> Thanks to extensive practice with the crossbow, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - ...
> - Being within 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn’t impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls.
>
> ...

So, does this mean that Crossbow Experts are the only PC's who can throw a net without disadvantage?

Comment: Related: [Are attacks with nets always made with disadvantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47754/33707)

Comment: FYI the related question noted by Sdjz has an answer that answers this exact question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, this build works

Since the Crossbow Expert feat allow you to make ranged attacks within 5 feet of your enemy without disadvantage, and the net's short range is 5 feet (the only range it can be thrown without gaining disadvantage via the long range rules), then this build can allow you to throw the net at point blank range without disadvantage.

#### There is at least one other build that can throw nets without disadvantage

If a PC had the Sharpshooter feat (PHB, p. 170), they would be able to throw the net at long range (10-15 feet) without disadvantage due to this benefit:

> - Attacking at long range doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged weapon attack rolls.

Comment: You can also avoid disadvantage without a feat by being hidden or invisible at close range.