# A way around Nets?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, throwing-things

So as a party we were all given bizarre items are a reward:

- A returning arrow, so it would come back to the ranger that fired it
- A shield which as an action could be deployed as 3/4 cover for creatures under 6ft and 1/2 cover for those below 8ft. (takes an action to pick back up)
- A scimitar which does fire damage during the day and cold during the night
- And an "unbreakable net"

We're able to see the value in the first 3 items but the net has us asking some questions:

1. Do nets roll with disadvantage on all attacks? Since they're a ranged attack with a range of 5ft
2. Would a net use Strength or Dexterity? Since both the rogue and fighter seem interested in it
3. Does it have to use an action or can you use a bonus action to throw it? Like with the Two Weapon Fighting rules?

Comment: I think your first question is answered here: [Do nets always attack with disadvantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47754/23970)