# Would the Ranger be overpowered if their Animal Companion kept attacking once ordered?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, ranger, animal-companions

For an Animal Companion to attack, the Ranger has to use his action to command it.

I am looking to see some math on just why this restriction is in place. Is the ranger way over-powered if the animal companion can keep attacking once ordered, or if gets to attack as an interact with object or verbal command from the ranger?

I'd like to see calculations for the following 3 scenarios:

- act as rules as written
- continue an action once given (1st attack takes a ranger action to activate)
- act as an interact with object by the ranger

How does the above compare with an identical ranger with colossus slayer?

I am hoping to understand why the designers limited it so much.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46158/does-the-rangers-companion-synergize-with-the-ranger is somewhat of an answer to this already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## In a word: Yes.

While it may be fairly well-accepted (though debatable) that a Beast Master Ranger is weaker than a Hunter Ranger, allowing the beast to attack freely swings things wildly in the other direction.

For the purposes of demonstration, I'll be using a basic Longbow Ranger, taking the Archery fighting style, starting with 16 dexterity, and taking +2 dex at level 4 and 8 to reach 20 dexterity. I'll be ignoring feats and other ranger builds to keep things simple, but they wouldn't really change the end result much anyways.

I'm using Damage per Round (DpR) as my measuring stick, taking into account chance to hit and chance to crit, using an average enemy AC at each level to get as practical a number as I can.

### Basic Longbow Ranger

- Level 3: **5.5 DpR**
- Level 5: **13.1 DpR**
- Level 11: **16.6 DpR**
- Level 20: **15.7 DpR**

### Wolf Animal Companion:

- Level 3: **5.2 DpR**
- Level 5: **6.8 DpR**
- Level 11: **16.1 DpR**
- Level 20: **17.0 DpR**

### Longbow Ranger with Colossus Slayer:

- Level 3: **9.6 DpR**
- Level 5: **18.4 DpR**
- Level 11: **21.0 DpR**
- Level 20: **20.0 DpR**

### Longbow Ranger plus Companion:

- Level 3: **10.7 DpR**
- Level 5: **20.9 DpR**
- Level 11: **32.7 DpR**
- Level 20: **32.7 DpR**

As you can see, while things start out OK at low levels, with the Ranger+Beast combo coming out only a bit ahead of the Colossus Slayer, this quickly changes once the Beast gets it's second attack. At this point, the ranger is now competing toe-to-toe with the better Fighter builds for damage potential.

Requiring the Beastmaster to use an action for the initial beast attack helps balance this out a bit, but ultimately it's still very powerful, and probably not wise to allow. As an interaction, it's just straight-up overpowered.

Comment: Thanks this will help a lot when looking at a possible house rule.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95884/discussion-on-answer-by-agentpaper-would-the-ranger-be-overpowered-if-their-anim).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to compare beast master to a longbow ranger. The main problems are: 1.Melee has an inherent bonus compared to ranged for balance reasons. 2. The beast is a separate entity and can be killed far easier than the ranger - typically the pet has worse AC (often 1 or 2 points behind) and half-ish hp. This means that the companion is only about 30-40% as tanky as the ranger at most levels. Factored in, the beasmaster dealing a bit more damage doesn't seem as bad.

Comment: @gszavae The pet being 30-40% as tanky as the ranger means that the ranger is 30-40% tankier than usual. The pet taking damage instead of someone else is a boon, not a penalty.

Comment: @AgentPaper Usually 5e characters are just as strong at 1% hp as they are at 100%. For the beastmaster, they lose half their DPR once they take ~25% damage. This is a massive disadvantage.

Answer (score 8):

## In a word: No

(The Ranger would **not** be overpowered if their Animal Companion kept attacking once ordered.)

Companions must have a challenge rating 1/4 or lower. Many beasts that a player may choose are not capable of attacks of any consequence. Examples; cat, frog, bat, hawk, raven etc. only deal 1 damage point.

A player's choice to use a companion that is unthreatening may have more to do with their character's background or role-play interests. The companion being able to attack on its own brings more realism to the game as real animals would defend themselves if attacked and would not require a verbal command every 6 seconds. It also brings more consistency to the game world as NPC beasts act on their own.

WOTC acknowledged in the preface of [Unearthed Arcana: Revised Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) that the Ranger Archetype beast master has been unpopular to play as it is underpowered.

> Many players want to play rangers, but few were happy with the class,
> which held its place at the bottom of class power rankings by a
> significant margin. The class’s individual features also filled the
> top-tenlist of lowest-rated individual character features.

They attempted to rectify the issue with specific changes to the animal companion in the Revised Ranger archetype **Beast Conclave** allowing the companion to attack on its own.

The companion may take its own initiative and turn controlled by the player. The companion also gains the following features in addition to its own attack: at level 5, it may attack as a reaction to your attack; at level 11, it may attack multiple enemies during its attack on its own turn.

> #### Coordinated Attack
>
> Beginning at 5th level, you and your animal companion form a more potent
> fighting team. When you use the Attack action on your turn, if your companion
> can see you, it can use its reaction to make a melee attack.
>
> #### Storm of Claws and Fangs
>
> At 11th level, your companion can use its action to make a melee attack
> against each creature of its choice within 5 feet of it, with a separate
> attack roll for each target.

Keep in mind that the base Revised Ranger class does not get an extra attack at level 5.

The beast cannot multi-attack.

Comment: Hey @Amethyst Wizard. We're looking into the UA at our table currently and have interpreted the section you've quoted about Coordinated Attack and Strom of Claws and Fangs to be **in addition** to it's normal attack, which is can take on its own turn without prompting. So level 3 = 1 attack, level 5 = 1 attack + 1 reaction attack, level 11 = 1 attack against all creatures within 5ft + 1 reaction attack. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yeah I totally agree, keep in mind Storm of Claws and Fangs is the beasts action.

Comment: Nice, I've tweaked your answer to clarify this, feel free to reject if you don't like my wording but I do recommend adjusting to your own as currently the "_at level 11:_" part reads as if that is the first chance it gets to attack on its own merit.

Answer (score 2):

It would be overpowered compared to other Ranger variations.
I don't believe it would be overpowered next to a fighter or other damage dealer.
As is, the ranger kind of specializes in clearing small minions, but doesn't do the best job, and a companion that attacks one target continuously would help fill in some single target dps, an animal that continues to attack unguided may be overkill but would make the ranger a master in the role of multi target take down.

Answer (score -3):

It wouldn’t be and is not, as confirmed by [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1067565833881145344) you would only need to make the attack command once for it to attack and only when you want to change that command would you need to use another action to command it.

> **nothingjacob**
>
> @JeremyECrawford there’s been some debate in the RAW community. Can Ranger BM give their companion a command like ‘attack’ and have the animal continue to attack each turn without issuing the command on consecutive turns ......? Thanks
>
> **Jeremy Crawford**
>
> Ranger's Companion—when you and the companion are fighting as a unit, the beast takes whatever action on its turn that you chose for it on your previous turn. If you chose no action for it on your previous turn, it takes the Dodge action on its turn.
>
> --- [Tweeted Nov 27 2018 by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1067565833881145344)

Comment: The JC tweet you're quoting here says the opposite of what you think it is saying - he's explicitly saying *no*, it will not continue attacking, it will start taking the dodge action unless you keep ordering it to attack.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please note that as of the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium JC's tweets are no longer considered official and so may support an answer but is not sufficient on its own. Also, please include the actual text as text in your answer (it helps folk with reading assist features etc.) Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Cubic “the beast takes whatever action on its turn that you chose for it on your previous turn”  The key word is “previous” as in your last turn not your current turn.

Comment: @Someone_Evil If as you say  “as of the 2019 Sage Advice Compendium JC's tweets are no longer considered official” how is a 2018 tweet not still official.

Comment: @Silver I am [quoting](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium): "The public statements of the D&D team, or anyone else at Wizards of the Coast, are not official rulings; they are advice. Jeremy Crawford’s tweets are often a preview of rulings that will appear here." As no mention of time is made, that means all his tweets are not official rulings.

Comment: @Silver There is only one previous turn, the turn you took before the beast took its turn (the beast doesn't act on your turn, it acts after you on its own turn but at your initiative). If you didn't order it to do anything in particular on that turn, it doesn't take an action.

Comment: @Silver: Prior to the 2019 SAC, Crawford tweets *could* be considered official rulings. [As of the 2019 SAC, none of Crawford's tweets are official rulings.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi) Crawford explains his reasoning, coincidentally, in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1105277917582389248): "As of the January edition of the Sage Advice Compendium PDF, my tweets aren't official rulings. I don't want people having to sift through my tweets for official rules calls. [...]"

Comment: @Cubic you’re misinformed, your argument is based on the theory that the beast and BM have separate turns.This is not the case, the beast acts on the BMs turn, the turn is shared. Pg96 PBH “The beast obeys your commands as best as it can. It takes its turn on your initiative” nowhere dose it say it takes its turn after yours. Infact it would contradict class features like “Once you have the Extra Attack feature, you can make one weapon attack yourself when you command the beast to take the attack action” how would BM attack after the beast attacks if you claim the beast takes its turn after BM

Comment: You attack after you command the beast to attack, not after it attacks. Turns are per creature, the line about initiative just means the beast doesn't make a separate initiative roll. It does indeed not say that the companion acts after the ranger, but the alternative would be it acting before the ranger which would make it useless.

Comment: @Cubic That’s a big reach, That suggests  that the beast, who is supposed to be “magically bonded to you”, acts more like a robot with the attention span of a toddler. Never be able to use the help action to help BM. Having to yell “follow” constantly when traveling  and since an entire round is 6 seconds, you would be yelling attack every second constantly if you want your beast to attack because otherwise it would sit idle as you get mauled by a bear. an orc chief being attacked by a human, and the orc chief “commands” his orc fighter to “attack” the human. He wouldn’t attack once and stop.

Comment: You can dislike it as much as you want - plenty of people do - but that is how the rules for this subclass are written, yes.

Comment: @Cubic it not a matter of liking or disliking the subclass, there’s is alota evidence in the rules as written to support what I’m saying. you’re claiming The opposite with no proof, sources, or reasoning. It’s sounding less and less like you actually want to find the answer and more like you just don’t want to admit you were wrong.

Comment: You’re free to ask a question about it if you like. Don’t have the space to do a detailed breakdown of how the ranger (or turns for that matter) works in a comment.

Comment: @Cubic we have the same amount of space to write and I have supported my claims. Where as you have just been taking the opposition but not supporting anything you’re saying. If there’s something you don’t understand you’re the one who should ask me questions. How is someone supposed to have a productive conversation, when one person states his case and support it with evidence and the other person just says no I’m right.

Comment: The rules are a lot more clear than JC, the RAW says "attack action", so you aren't just telling your pet "go attack that guy!" you are specifically instructing them to take 1 action.